# What is the origin of the term "clanker"?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

As frequently used by clone troopers during the Clone Wars, when was the term invented, how and why, and when did it come into common GAR use (if they didn't invent it)?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_phrases_and_slang):

> **Clanker**: Clone troopers sometimes used this term to describe CIS battle droids in reference to the clanking sound they made while marching.

This is sourced to the Clone Wars episode [*Ambush*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ambush) (the [decoded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(TV_series)#Decoded) version with popup boxes containing trivia and behind-the-scenes information).

Comment: Was that the first use of the term in the cartoon or the first use of the term in the war? There's a difference, and I'm searching for in-universe history answers

Comment: @thegreatjedi I don't know about first use, but this quote does seem to be about the in-universe origin of the name.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I remember hearing the term in the video game [*Republic Commando*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic_Commando), which predates the referenced episode, but the game is Legends.

Answer (score 5):

The adventures of Delta Squad throughout [Republic Commando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic_Commando) are the first time the term is used in Star Wars, with Dave Filoni taking the term and implementing it in the Clone Wars three years later. This would ultimately seem to suggest that the term originated with the clone commandos, presumably due to their more free-minded natures leading them to perhaps act in ways which would be either less common or seen as being defective among the common clones. With the commandos providing such a huge boost to morale amongst clones, it's easy to see that their leadership and strength would lead to common clones co-opting their little flairs and lingo.

> **Clone Advisor 1:** *The Trandoshans have been more concerned with acquiring Wookiee pelts than taking sides in this war.*
>
> **Delta 40:** *Then what are they doing here? **And why would the seps be selling clankers to slavers***

Republic Commando *is* considered to be Legends content, however the characters of Delta Squad are seen in the Clone Wars, suggesting that there's some gray area in terms of what's canon about them and what isn't, with the only solid thing provided in canon being their existence.

Comment: _"Lousy clanker."_ - RC Delta 01/207 "Sev" - https://youtu.be/V4BAR8jMfJg?t=245

I'm fairly certain it's said multiple times, I just remember hearing the line as I started replaying yesterday in passing, this was the first line I came across which used the term, and with something like 45 minutes of voice lines, I'm a little bit too lazy to go through it all looking for it, but it shows up at least through Sev.

Comment: Another mention from him is in the intro to the level called "Attack of the Clones" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJTKz9744qM just ran into this now myself not a minute ago.